# Choppy Scrolling Issue Wordpress on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

**The issue**

There is an issue with one page on my website, the scrolling is choppy. It only seems to happen on Google Chrome. When you first scroll, its jumps down rather than have a smooth scroll.

**External link to my site**

[cryptocoincheckup.com/shop-merch/](https://cryptocoincheckup.com/shop-merch/)

If you scroll fast it looks fine, it's only when you wait a few seconds then scroll up or down once. I contacted the theme author and they can't replicate it, but tried it on 4 computers and all have it. Not sure what could be causing it, only on this one page.

I saw others say it might be large images, so I tried removing all of the products, and still had the issue.

Comment: It's pretty clear what the issue is, I'm having an issue with the scrolling experience. It's only on the one page.

Answer (score 1):

There is JavaScript intercepting and overriding scroll wheel. This is quite common in themes.

If you don't mind editing the theme JavaScript, you'll need to modify `plugins.js` and remove the `smooth scroll` at lines 49-50.

Here's the current URL path to the file:

`https://cryptocoincheckup.com/wp-content/themes/dfd-native/assets/js/plugins.min.js`

Here's the bit you want to remove:

```
/*smooth scroll*/
!function(a){a(window).load(function(){a.browser.chrome=/chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()),!navigator.platform.match(/(Mac|iPhone|iPod|iPad)/i)&&a.browser.chrome&&a("body").hasClass("dfd-smooth-scroll")&&function(){function b(){if(document.body){var a=document.body,b=document.documentElement,c=window.innerHeight,d=a.scrollHeight;if(G=0<=document.compatMode.indexOf("CSS")?b:a,H=a,E=!0,top!=self)C=!0;else if(d>c&&(a.offsetHeight<=c||b.offsetHeight<=c)){var e=!1,d=function(){e||b.scrollHeight==document.height||(e=!0,setTimeout(function(){b.style.height=document.height+"px",e=!1},500))};b.style.height="auto",setTimeout(d,10),i("DOMNodeInserted",d),i("DOMNodeRemoved",d),G.offsetHeight<=c&&(c=document.createElement("div"),c.style.clear="both",a.appendChild(c))}-1<document.URL.indexOf("mail.google.com")&&(c=document.createElement("style"),c.innerHTML=".iu { visibility: hidden }",(document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]||b).appendChild(c)),F||B||(a.style.backgroundAttachment="scroll",b.style.backgroundAttachment="scroll")}}function c(b,c,d,e){if(e||(e=1e3),l(c,d),u){var f=+new Date-L;v>f&&(f=(1+30/f)/2)>1&&(f=Math.min(f,w),c*=f,d*=f),L=+new Date}if(J.push({x:c,y:d,lastX:0>c?.99:-.99,lastY:0>d?.99:-.99,start:+new Date}),!K){if(a("body").hasClass("top-inner-page-initializing")||a("#layout").hasClass("one-page-scroll"))return;var g=b===document.body,h=function(){for(var a=+new Date,f=0,i=0,j=0;j<J.length;j++){var k=J[j],l=a-k.start,m=l>=p,q=m?1:l/p;r&&(q=n(q)),l=k.x*q-k.lastX>>0,q=k.y*q-k.lastY>>0,f+=l,i+=q,k.lastX+=l,k.lastY+=q,m&&(J.splice(j,1),j--)}g?window.scrollBy(f,i):(f&&(b.scrollLeft+=f),i&&(b.scrollTop+=i)),c||d||(J=[]),J.length?O(h,b,e/o+1):K=!1};O(h,b,0),K=!0}}function d(a){E||b();var d=a.target,e=h(d);if(!e||a.defaultPrevented||k(H,"embed")||k(d,"embed")&&/\.pdf/i.test(d.src))return!0;var d=a.wheelDeltaX||0,f=a.wheelDeltaY||0;d||f||(f=a.wheelDelta||0),1.2<Math.abs(d)&&(d*=q/120),1.2<Math.abs(f)&&(f*=q/120),c(e,-d,-f),a.preventDefault()}function f(a){H=a.target}function g(a,b){for(var c=a.length;c--;)M[N(a[c])]=b;return b}function h(a){var b=[],c=G.scrollHeight;do{var d=M[N(a)];if(d)return g(b,d);if(b.push(a),c===a.scrollHeight){if(!C||G.clientHeight+10<c)return g(b,document.body)}else if(a.clientHeight+10<a.scrollHeight&&(overflow=getComputedStyle(a,"").getPropertyValue("overflow-y"),"scroll"===overflow||"auto"===overflow))return g(b,a)}while(a=a.parentNode)}function i(a,b,c){window.addEventListener(a,b,c||!1)}function k(a,b){return(a.nodeName||"").toLowerCase()===b.toLowerCase()}function l(a,b){a=a>0?1:-1,b=b>0?1:-1,(D.x!==a||D.y!==b)&&(D.x=a,D.y=b,J=[],L=0)}function m(a){var b;return a*=s,1>a?b=a-(1-Math.exp(-a)):(b=Math.exp(-1),a=1-Math.exp(-(a-1)),b+=a*(1-b)),b*t}function n(a){return a>=1?1:0>=a?0:(1==t&&(t/=m(1)),m(a))}var H,o=150,p=800,q=150,r=!0,s=6,t=1,u=!0,v=20,w=1,B=!1,C=!1,D={x:0,y:0},E=!1,F=!0,G=document.documentElement,J=[],K=!1,L=+new Date,M={};setInterval(function(){M={}},1e4);var N=function(){var a=0;return function(b){return b.uniqueID||(b.uniqueID=a++)}}(),O=function(){return window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||function(a,b,c){window.setTimeout(a,c||1e3/60)}}();i("mousedown",f),i("mousewheel",d),i("load",b)}()})}(jQuery);
```

Warning: This may have unintended side effects. Try it and see what happens :)

Comment: Ok, I commented the code out, still choppy. :/

Comment: @Garrettj944 make sure to clear cache or do hard refresh (CTRL/CMD+F5) to ensure browser is using the new copy. You can also go to https://cryptocoincheckup.com/wp-content/themes/dfd-native/assets/js/plugins.min.js in browser and press F5 to refresh, then refresh the web page.

Comment: I did. It's not very noticeable but it's still there. I know it's not a huge deal but I'd pay to get this fixed.